# Importing data from CSV file into SQL database through Python and getting "invalid input syntax for type integer:" for a column that is a VARCHAR

Tags: python, sql, csv, psycopg2

I've now spent countless of hours troubleshooting this error, before making a post here, to no avail.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
Import data from a CSV file into an SQL database using Python and psycopg2. Ideally without making any changes to the CSV file.

Here's my issue:
TLDR: DB is set up for varchar/string data, yet somehow I'm getting a "invalid input syntax for type integer:" error.
Here's the code that successfully creates the "Customers_1" table:

```
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers_1;')
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE customers_1 (customer_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,'
                                 'Kundenummer varchar(100),'
                                 'Start_year integer,'
                                 'Navn varchar(100),'
                                 'Land varchar(100),'
                                 'Segment varchar(20));'
                                 )
```

Everthing should be in order here, and when I run a basic INSERT INTO command I can enter the values just fine as seen in this screenshot from pgAdmin:
[customers_1 table with 1 row successfully added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuGmB.png)

I attempt to import the CSV data using the "copy_from" function as seen here:

```
f = open(r'Eksamen2\customer_segment.csv', 'r')
cur.copy_from(f, 'customers_1', sep=',')
f.close()
```

My CSV file includes a header, however, removing it did not fix the issue. Here's a look at the first two lines of the CSV file:

> Kundenummer,Start_year,Navn,Land,Segment

> K816058744,2019,GearBicycle  ,Norge,Medium

The program returns this error message:

> cur.copy_from(f, 'customers_1', sep=',')
> psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "Kundenummer"
> CONTEXT:  COPY customers_1, line 1, column customer_id: "Kundenummer"

I don't understand why it is expecting an integer here, as the column "Kundenummer" is a varchar.
I'm considering simply turning the SQL text into a query and creating a for loop that goes through the CSV file, however that seems more complicated than simply using the copy_from function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Bonus question: I'd like to ditch the "customer_id" PK in favour of simply using the "Kundenummer" column as the PK. However, I'm unable to create a SERIAL for that PK that would automatically generate a customer number starting with K, followed by 8 or 9 numbers, like the customer IDs in my CSV file.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using pgAdmin 4.

Comment: It looks like the error is on the column customer_id, which is the serial, so I think your problem is that it's trying to fill customer_id with a value that's not in your CSV, as it doesn't have the serial.

Comment: You're right! I forgot that I wasn't specifying which columns to import the data into, so of course it attempted to fill data into my unique serial PK, that was actually expecting an integer. Thank you so much!

In case someone makes this same error, you can specify which columns to fill in a copy_from function by adding "columns=('columnName', 'columnname2') into the parenthesis of the copy_from function.
The bellow changes fixed mine:

`cur.copy_from(f, 'customers_1', sep=',', columns=('kundenummer', 'start_year', 'navn', 'land', 'segment'))`